# Replacing embedded apostrophes, but only certain ones (part 2)

Tags: c#, sql, regex, string

Actually I've now realised I was trying to solve the wrong problem yesterday (but I learned some useful tips along the way - thanks to all).

My problem is that really I need to replace apostrophes embedded in any literal string within a string, eg

> " and x = 'o'reilly' and y = 'o'reilly' and z = 'some text with a 'word here' in it' "

to become

> " and x = 'o''reilly' and y = 'o''reilly' and z = 'some text with a ''word here'' in it' "

And yes, this is preparing arbitrary text constructed dynamically from user input and other sources to be  part of a sql query. I can't rely on spaces being where I might expect them, nor can I rely on the presence or absence of spaces either side of equals signs, for instance.

Comment: If you can't rely on the format of the input string, then this problem seems unsolvable. Where is that sample string constructed? You have to remove apostrophes *before* you glue that string together.

Comment: If you are preparing text from user input as part of a SQL query, then you must know to use parameters instead. Why not just use parameters?

Comment: I agree with @fejesjoco - what an apostrophe represents in your string (either a substring wrapped with single quotes or an apostrophe) doesn't seem to be well-defined.

Comment: this is a vulnerable approach, anyone with basic skills in SQL can disappoint you and your app, use something different

Comment: It's not just vulnerable. There are four different possible requests for what `x`, `y` and/or `z` can be compared to, which would all result in the string in this question. That is there are four correct answers and no way to know that e.g. `and x = 'o''reilly'' and y = ''o''reilly'' and z = ''some text with a ''word here'' in it'` (comparing just `x`) isn't what is really wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following to replace the embedded '...

```
string output = Regex.Replace(" and x = 'o'reilly' and y = 'o'reilly' and z = 'some text with a 'word here' in it' ", @"(?<=\=\s*\'[\w\s]*?)\'(?=[\w\s]*?\')", @"""");
```

Good Luck!

Here is the screenshot of the code and output...

[image]

Comment: i'm sorry bu i must destroy your classy repo number =] (666)

Comment: :) Thanks for breaking the spell!

Comment: Have you tried this? Aside from the typo of `""` instead of `''`, it doesn't work.

Comment: Added screenshot for your reference

Comment: Your screenshot proves it doesn't work. You're producing ` and x = 'o"reilly' and y = 'o"reilly' and z = 'some text with a 'word here' in it'` when the desired result is ` and x = 'o''reilly' and y = 'o''reilly' and z = 'some text with a ''word here'' in it'`

Comment: Updated the answer. Try that for size.

Comment: Yes, that's a different wrong answer. You're replacing `'` with `"` instead of `''`, and also missing two places where it should be replaced.

Comment: I am unclear on what you are looking for. If you can tell me what you are looking I can try to help.

Comment: They gave an example of what they were looking for in the question.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid the basic problem is provably impossible.

You've got something of the form:

```
and name1 = 'value1' [and name2 = 'value2' [...]]
```

Where the values may contain zero or more apostrophes.

However unless the values are not allowed to contain equals signs, then there's no way to know whether the example you give:

```
 and x = 'o'reilly' and y = 'o'reilly' and z = 'some text with a 'word here' in it'
```

Should be interpreted. Consider, if we wanted to do:

1. compare `x` with `o'reilly`
2. compare `y` with `o'reilly`
3. compare `z` with `some text with a 'word here' in it`

Then you would end up with the string in your example.

However, if we wanted to do:

1. compare `x` with `o'reilly'  and y = 'o'reilly`
2. compare `z` with `some text with a 'word here' in it`

Then we would also end up with the string in your example.

(There are two other possible requests that would also result in the exact same string).

The purpose of your code is to turn a string describing part of an intended operation into code that performs that operation.

The bug is that the string does not clearly describe that intended operation.

It's possible to fix the most likely cases (that the value never contains `and foo = '`), but a general solution is impossible. You need to fix what is serialising the predicates in this way, as that's where the bug is.

Edit: If we can assume that we'll never get an ambiguous case, then we can make use of:

```
Regex.Replace(
  input,
  @"'(.*?)'(?=\s*(and\s+\S+\s*=\s*'|$))",
  m => "'" + m.Value.Substring(1, m.Value.Length - 2).Replace("'", "''") + '\''
)
```

However, I'd only use this as a matter of last resort, along with filing a bug against the fact that it's being done, because it still has the problems I detailed above, it's just the best that can be done in the meantime.

Comment: Thanks - unsolvable problems are what I get given. :-).

Comment: Well, I added something that deals with the more likely cases, which might work as a stop-gap, but the unsolvable ambiguity remains. Perhaps use this but also complain about the ambiguity so it can get fixed eventually. (Or at the very least, so you can show that you had already pointed out the issue, if you get the blame for it causing problems down the line).

Comment: Incidentally, if the names of the possible fields is a finite set, you can replace `\S+` above with e.g. `x|y|z|foo|bar` and reduce the possible misinterpretations further. You just can't reduce them to 0% risk, for the reasons I gave above.

Answer (score 0):

Is this application facing the web? I'm a SQL junkie, I need to inject some SQL.

In other words, **don't do this!**

Find another way to do what you want to do, for instance using a parameterized query.

```
string query = "SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE x = @x AND y = @y AND z = @z";
// Assuming we have a connection object conn
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, conn); 
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@x", "o'Reilly");
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@y", "o'Reilly");
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@z", "some text with a 'word here' in it");
```

Comment: Yes in general. They may not know that the fields they care about are `x`, `y` and `z` at the point where they're doing this, so it may be further up the stack that they need to re-design, so as to let this approach be possible.

Comment: No, it's only on an intranet. The users don't enter the sql directly, they enter some text (possibly) which inter alia contributes to a sql expression. Not invented here, but I have to deal with it. And parameters are out - user text has to be something ordinary people understand.